# Fixed dimensions on looker

Tags: analysis, looker

I have a report that I am trying to migrate from tableau to looker. I do have fixed fields like below on my report. Is there a way to create this statement on looker without using derived table? Otherwise it is gong to be really complicated on Views once we migrate all our reports.

`{ FIXED [Employee Id]:MAX( IF NOT ISNULL([Taşıyıcı end date]) THEN [Taşıyıcı end date] END)}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to create this statement on looker without using derived table?

Unfortunately no - the only solution is derived table (as you mentioned).